# How do I safely write to a file while a third party program reads from it?

Tags: python, file-io

A third party program reads from a text file periodically. A python script of mine writes to the same text file periodically. What happens if the third party program tries to read the file while my script is busy writing to it? How can I do this in a safe way?

Comment: If you only can control your python, check out the access method in os: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_access.htm

Comment: One safe way to do this is to use the multiprocessing module https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Try exploring this file lock mechanism https://github.com/dmfrey/FileLock